# joda datetime deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime

I am trying to figure out if Joda DateTime is serializable (when using default Java serializable) or do I need to provide my own serialization implementation (using externalizable or a third party serialization library).  Currently, I tried serializing and deserializing a class containing an instance variable of type Joda DateTime but I get a serialzation exception for DateTime.

**relevant section of class**

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

private DateTime dateTime;

    protected DateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    protected void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
```

Comment: DateTime class implements Serializable it should work just fine. Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: throwing this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LDateTime;.  Checking whether I have a typo somewhere in my project but when I searched via eclipse, it could not find LDateTime in the project.  I am using joda time v2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joda DateTime is serializable - the error you're sharing could be a project issue.  Try cleaning and building the project again to see if the issue gets resolved.  Are there are any other errors in the project or after you run the project?